# Cartoon with an evil scientist/doctor

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

All I can remember is that he was a cartoon villain who was super old, in a wheelchair, had a huge forehead, with purple glasses, and had a white lab coat on. I'm pretty sure he was a doctor or evil scientist. It was an older cartoon shown on Cartoon Network I think. I used to watch it as a kid so around 1998-2004.

[image: evil looking scientist]

The photo is a fan art I found that looks very similar to him. The one I am talking about is much more cartoon-like.

Comment: How old is it? When did you see this? Can you remember any plot elements?

Comment: [Dexter's Laboratory?](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzdlMDMxNzItNmViNS00NDRkLTg3OWMtNjliZGIxY2M5N2YyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA4NzY1MzY@._V1_UY268_CR1,0,182,268_AL_.jpg)

Comment: Did you see multiple episodes of the show? Was this villain a regular on the show, vs. a one-time opponent? Also, anything in particular that would make him "super old"? Liver spots, old man's voice, something attitudinal? Any recollection of who he would have been a villain *of*?

Comment: When you say "an older cartoon on Cartoon Network", do you say "older" because you watched it 15-20 years ago, or "older" because it seemed like a cartoon that was made years before you were watching it (as in, the cartoon might have been made in the 1960s, but you were seeing it in the 1990s/2000s)

Comment: I say older because he was bald, in a wheel chair. He had small wrinkles lines. He talked like an older man. I've seen him in multiple episodes. I would say it was made between 1995-2000.

Comment: I added a photo that someone drew that looks like him.

Comment: Traditional animation, or 3D CGI style? If the first - anime-style, or Western? Also - how certain are you that it was on Cartoon Network? Could it actually have been on Nickelodeon, for instance?

Comment: I know you're not making him up. I have a vague memory but I can't seem to remember the name and all his episodes took place in a desert-like setting. He had a missile/conehead that had to be held up with a cane. For the life of me can't remember his name but I can braw what my mind remembers.

Comment: The image isn't "fan art". It's from the MAD Magazine tv show on Cartoon Network, specifically a [hand sanitizer commercial parody](https://maditsmadfunny.fandom.com/wiki/Villain_Hand_Sanitizer).

Answer (score 5):

Is there a possibility you're conflating several characters together?

The character you posted a picture of is from an episode of the Mad Magazine cartoon, from a bit about [Villain Hand Sanitizer](http://maditsmadfunny.wikia.com/wiki/Villain_Hand_Sanitizer).

The character you've described is also a pretty good description of Dr. Finkelstein from The Nightmare Before Christmas.

[image]

But he wasn't on Cartoon Network.

General Immortus, from the Teen Titans show, was on Cartoon Network

[image]

But didn't use a wheelchair - though Chief, leader of the Doom Patrol did.

There's also the mad scientist from Robot Chicken, the ANGRY scientist from Sheep in the Big City, and any number of mad scientists from Courage the Cowardly Dog

To sum up, some more detail might help narrow things down a bit.

Answer (score 5):

[*Biker Mice from Mars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biker_Mice_from_Mars)'s Dr. Karbunkle is quite similar to the image you posted and fits *some* of the characteristics you list:

- old
- huge forehead
- white lab coat
- evil doctor/scientist

but there are a few differencies too:

- he wears *green* glasses, not purple ones
- he is not completely bald
- no wheelchair
- according to Wikipedia the series ran from 1993 to 1996, though there is also a 2006 reboot

[image]

<sub>(image from [super-villain.wikia.com](http://super-villain.wikia.com))</sub>

Comment: I feel like I'm not adding them all up together. But who knows I was so young. I vividly remember him. The picture I posted isn't exactly him. The one I'm thinking of is much older and is a tiny frail man with a large forehead and bald. He had a automatic willchair and he was always rubbing his hands together with a white lab coat.

Answer (score 4):

The art serving as your example is from a parody show, [Cartoon Network’s MAD, Season 1, Episode 13](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1718438/), not “fan art.” ( Your source may be fan art, but the character it may be based on is a parody character, not any real series’ character).

The character is in the group shot at right just before your picture is shown in the parody commercial — as the announcer shouts “You guessed it!”

[image]

The “actual” character is much more cartoony looking; however both versions of the art (the realistic art you term “fan art” version and the cartoony version) both are originals shown in the parody commercial, so it’s not certain whether the cartoon is any “less canon” or “more real” representation of this nameless “Masterkind” parody than the realistic art version.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Bald man with an exaggerated forehead in a white coat, thick black glasses and black gloves]

Is it Dr. Who from [*The King Kong Show*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_Kong_Show)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is this character wheelchair-bound though? If he is, you should [edit] your answer to mention that, as it'll reinforce how close a match this is to the character described in the question.

Comment: The [page on Villains Wiki for Dr. Who](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Dr._Who_(King_Kong)) doesn't mention a wheelchair; are you certain this is a match?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Jeremiah Surd from real adventures of johny quest? Around 1997.
Doesnt have a white coat but matches other things you said

Answer (score 0):

Doctor Sivana from Shazam is who you are trying to remember.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  But was he ever in a wheelchair?  And can you find an image of him wearing purple glasses?

Comment: Also, was Dr. Sivana in a cartoon shown on Cartoon Network circa 1998-2004...? If the answer to all of these questions is "no", then this is very unlikely to be the correct answer.