# Evil scientist from a cartoon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have in mind an old scientist, dressed in a white robe with round, dark glasses and gloves. Physically he looks pretty much like this[image]

But with very little hair. I remember seeing him I think on Cartoon Network but I might be wrong, sometime between 2009-2014. I can't remember anything else about him unfortunately. Does somebody have an idea who I'm talking about?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Biker Mice from Mars, maybe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195264/20774?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195255/cartoon-with-an-evil-scientist-doctor

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I just said that :-)

Comment: Reminds me of the [Mad Scientist from *Robot Chicken*](https://robotchicken.fandom.com/wiki/Mad_Scientist).  What was the animation style?

Comment: Great minds... or similar search terms.

Comment: What was science-fiction or fantasy about him?

Comment: Even if this is SFF-Nal it is incredibly broad. Can you remember anything at all about the cartoon or even what this character does that you could edit in?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't remember anything else about him and I tried. I'm not even sure if he was a normal villain or the main villain sidekick. I only have in mind an image with him. If it helps, I tried searching him on the internet in cartoons I thought he might belong to, like _Shaggy & Scooby get a clue_, where those acolytes had the same glasses I remember the scientist had, or _Cowardly Dog_, _Dexter_, _Batman the Brave and the Bold_, _Teen Titans_, _Kim Possible_, _Powerpuff Girls_, even _Robot Boy_ where I barely remember the characters, but I couldn't find him anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be thinking of [Dr. Karbunkle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJ7dEGAFKhQ) from *Biker Mice from Mars*? He certainly fits the mad scientist trope, but notably has *very little hair*.

The show aired in the 1990s, but has been in syndication (including Cartoon Network) since 2000.

[image: Dr. Karbunkle]
[image: Dr. Karbunkle headshot]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a less blurry-looking picture.  Feel free to delete if it's not wanted.

Comment: @DavidW - I was trying to find a full body picture :-)